# I'm trying to make a test html where pressing a button moves along the index of an array which starts at 0

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

When I test this code it only shows 0, despite the button function running. What have I done wrong? Since I'm only starting out with JavaScript I'd appreciate an in-depth answer.

```js
var y = 1;
myFunction();

function myFunc() {
  var z = 1
  var x = y + z;
  y = x
  alert("f");
}

function myFunction() {
  y = 0;
  alert("sdrz");
}
const numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers[y];
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunc()">+1</button>
```

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from a bunch of other style issues, your innerHTML assignment was not in the onclick, "myFunc" handler, so it was never getting executed.  Also your function will exceed the array limits if clicked on too many times.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body >
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <button onclick="myFunc()">+1</button>
   <script>
   const numbers = ["0", "1", "2", "3"];
   var y=0;

   function myFunc() {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers[y];
     y++;
   }

   </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I don't know why I thought the <script> block constantly updated all code in it